# Are dosages of Saccharin Sodium in food are non-carcinogenic?

Tags: nutrition, food-safety, sodium, carcinogens, sweeteners

There is such sweetener as Saccharin Sodium that being added sometimes in drinks and just sold as sweetener on it's own.
I didn't found information about dosages, but but on nih.gov I see this:

> [There is sufficient evidence that this compound is an animal
>   carcinogen. When heated to decomposition this compound emits very
>   toxic fumes of SOx and NOx.](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Saccharin-sodium#section=Health-Hazard)

Also on the sweetener I've seen norm of daily consumption notion.
On the other hand I heard that 2nd generation of sweeteners are safe (aspartame), if so then may there be safe dosages for the 1st generation?

**The main question is if dosages they put in food and recommended daily norm on sweeteners are non-carcenogenic?**

Also it's not clear what temperatures are required for heating to decomposition? Can it be used in baking?

Comment: Would you add the link to the source of the quote?

Comment: @Jan just did it.

Comment: Answering such questions is ungratifying because rarely one believes it...I really suggest you to just check few other sites using the site:gov operator (mostly studies). Here's one: https://www.cancer.gov/about-cancer/causes-prevention/risk/diet/artificial-sweeteners-fact-sheet . Early research said yes, it is associated with bladder cancer, but newer research says "not sure"...

Comment: @Jan thanks. Believes to what exactly?

Comment: Some (mainly older) studies say yes, it's carcinogenic and some (mainly newer) studies say, it's "insufficient evidence" - and such answers may not be convincing for you. I just wanted that you actually find few other studies and check and taste the confusion. You may want to use a date filter (aka after 2010). If you are willing to do this, we can then discuss further. I mean PubChem, full respect, but they on their own are not an absolute reference.

Comment: I agree with @Jan and I am especially surprised to see *"It may also cause anorexia."* in there. The question also needing to be asked is what temperatures are required for heating to decomposition. Use in foods might not reach those temperatures

Comment: Are you talking about the stuff in the pink packs?  There is some research out of Israel that shows it could produce bad gut bacteria or something like that.  You can search for the details of that study.  I don’t think cancer was the concern but rather that it might actually contribute to Type 2 diabetes.  The pink packs I think.  But find the study for proper details.

Comment: You can do some research on cyclamates too.  Supposedly legal in Canada, Mexico and Australia and other places too I guess. The USA may have banned this one too quickly. I think they fed the rats with like “tons” of it and they got cancer.

Comment: Israeli study mentioned here:  https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/artificial-sweeteners-may-change-our-gut-bacteria-in-dangerous-ways/

Comment: The answer is "yes" because there are non-carcinogenic doses of virtually everything.  Your question would be improved by clarifying what you mean.

Comment: @Carey Gregory I made clarification.

Comment: @Gordon thanks. Whatever brand/form - doesn't matter, I used liquid actually, like EZ-Sweetz.

Answer (score 1):

The PubChem article you linked ([National Center for Biotechnology Information, n.d.](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Saccharin-sodium)) stated that

> When heated to decomposition this compound emits very toxic fumes of SOx and NOx. It may also emit toxic fumes of carbon and COx. (NTP, 1992)

So what is the required heat for decomposition?

[Saad, et al. (2014)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fc15/178ca15502d3c0d64e7753eccb88e7bd73db.pdf) points out that

> Saccharin decomposes at 228°C [442.4°F] in acid (Lide, 1997); > 300°C [572°F] in sodium and calcium salts (Mitchell & Pearson, 1991)

You may be setting an oven at a higher temperature than 228°C/442.4°F and [a proper pizza oven should go above 500°C/932°F](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/46639/66538) but you need to remember that the food can't reach those temperatures without burning. In [another answer to the same Cooking.SE question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/46648/66538) we are reminded that

> air is a bad transmitter of heat. You can hold your hand in air that is 212℉ / 100℃, but you can’t put it into a pot of boiling water.

With frying temperatures, heating oil above 190°C may result in the oil catching fire ([BBC Good Food, n.d.](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/howto/guide/how-deep-fry-safely)).

With these facts in mind, cooking and baking does not involve heating food to these kinds of temperatures, so therefore this fact is irrelevant to food safety.

As for the carcinogenicity, of Saccharin they also state that

> [Arnold (1983)](https://doi.org/10.1289/ehp.835027) studied two generation saccharin bioassays. Results showed that humeral antibody production in rats is seriously affected that may lead toward cancer. In 1977 FDA proposed a ban on saccharin use due to cancer reports in laboratory rats (Arnold, 1984; Tisdel et al., 1974; Schoenig et al., 1985; Taylor et al., 1980).

The  results  of  the study by [Arnold (1983)](https://doi.org/10.1289/ehp.835027) resulted  in  the  prohibition  of  saccharin  in  Canada  and  a  proposed  ban  in  the United  States.  This  proposed  U.S.  ban  was withdrawn  in  1991,  but  foods  containing  saccharin  were required  to  carry  a  warning  label.  This  warning  label  was  placed  on all  products  containing  saccharin  to  indicate  “saccharin  is a  potential  cancer  causing  agent.”

Supporting evidence for carcinogenicity given by [Saad, et al. (2014)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fc15/178ca15502d3c0d64e7753eccb88e7bd73db.pdf) includes studies from the 80s and 90s:

> Exposure to pure saccharin supported its role in pathogenesis of the liver damage (Negro et al., 1994). Several studies have been done which shows association between bladder cancer and saccharine (Fukushima et al., 1986; Shibata et al., 1989; Cohen et al., 1991; Ito et al., 1983; Fukushima et al., 1983; Fukushima et al., 1986). All of the ingested saccharin after circulation in blood excreted through urine from body (Sweatman et al., 1981).

However, [Whitehouse, et al. (2008)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5247958_The_Potential_Toxicity_of_Artificial_Sweeteners) points out that (emphasis mine)

> [A  2007  article  by  Gallus  et  al.](https://academic.oup.com/annonc/article-pdf/18/1/40/794927/mdl346.pdf)  discussed  artificial sweeteners  and  associated  cancer  risks.  The  authors  reviewed  several  case-control  studies  and  **found  a  lack  of association  between  saccharine,  aspartame,  and  other sweeteners  and  several  common  neoplasms.  They  did cite  an  ecology  study  that  indicated  a  direct  correlation  between  brain  cancer  and  aspartame  consumption. These  studies  are  subject  to  ecological  fallacy  and  the hypothesis  was  not  confirmed  in  animal  or  human  studies**.

Research since [Arnold (1983)](https://doi.org/10.1289/ehp.835027) showing  the  safety  of saccharin led  to  the overturning of the decision to warning label products containing saccharin in the US in  2000.  A ban  on  saccharin  still  exists  in  Canada;  however,  Health Canada  is  currently  considering  relisting  saccharin  as  a food additive ([Whitehouse, et al. 2008](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5247958_The_Potential_Toxicity_of_Artificial_Sweeteners))

### References

Arnold, D. L. (1983). Two-generation saccharin bioassays. Environmental health perspectives, 50, 27-36. doi: [10.1289/ehp.835027](https://doi.org/10.1289/ehp.835027)

BBC Good Food (n.d.). *How to deep fry safely*. Retrieved from: https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/howto/guide/how-deep-fry-safely

Gallus,  S.,  Scotti,  L.,  Negri,  E.,  Talamini,  R.,  Franceschi,  S.,  Montella, M.,  et  al.  (2007).  Artificial  sweeteners  and  cancer  risk  in  a  network of case-control studies.  Annals of Oncology,  18(1), 40-44. doi: [10.1093/annonc/mdl346](https://doi.org/10.1093/annonc/mdl346) Free PDF retrieved from  https://academic.oup.com/annonc/article-pdf/18/1/40/794927/mdl346.pdf

National Center for Biotechnology Information. (n.d.) *PubChem Database. Saccharin sodium, CID=656582*. Retrieved from: https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Saccharin-sodium

Saad, A., Khan, F. A., Hayee, A., & Nazir, M. S. (2014). A review on potential toxicity of artificial sweetners vs safety of Stevia: a natural bio-sweetner. Journal of Biology, Agriculture and Healthcare, 4(15), 1-12. Free PDF retrieved from: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fc15/178ca15502d3c0d64e7753eccb88e7bd73db.pdf

Whitehouse, C. R., Boullata, J., & McCauley, L. A. (2008). The potential toxicity of artificial sweeteners. Aaohn Journal, 56(6), 251-261. doi: [10.3928/08910162-20080601-02](https://doi.org/10.3928/08910162-20080601-02) Free PDF retrieved from: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5247958_The_Potential_Toxicity_of_Artificial_Sweeteners